# What was the mass of the Hindenburg?

Tags: airship

What was the mass of a fully fueled Hindenburg (discounting any cargo other than fuel/gaz) ?

I do mean to **exclude** any lift provided by buoyancy.

Comment: You mean the weight of the airship plus fuel without any of the lifting gas?

Comment: I mean including the mass of the lifting gas

Comment: http://www.u-s-history.com/pages/h1648.html 242 Tons

Comment: "*What was the mass [...] exclude any lift provided by buoyancy*": lift/buoyancy are forces (N), they have no noticeable effects on mass (kg), unless they can propel the aircraft at relativistic velocity.

Comment: do you want to include the mass of the hydrogen or not?

Comment: Mass is independent of lift. If you took the Hindenburg out into the vacuum of space the mass would remain the same.

Comment: Steve, Federico: Yes and yes :)

Answer (score 8):

According to [airships.net](http://www.airships.net/helium-hydrogen-airships/), LZ-129 Hindenburg had a dead weight of 118,000 kg and carried 58,880 kg of fuel. So that comes to 176,880 kg. Here are the full details:

[image: Hindenburg]

Actual payload from a Hindenburg flight across the South Atlantic using hydrogen; table from [airships.net](http://www.airships.net/helium-hydrogen-airships/)

Comment: You forget the mass of the lifting gas, hydrogen in this case...